# R- two column comparision

Tags: r

I am very new in R programming. I was trying to columns two coloums. One column gives values of customers who has taken housing loans(in "yes" or "no") and another column gives information about person who has taken personal loan (in "yes" or "no") from the bank.

Now I wanted to know who are the customer who has taken both?

I was able to count the customers but not able to think beyond it.

let my data frame be `k` and columns be `housing` and `personal`

```
k <- housing personal
         yes      yes
          no      yes
         yes       no
         yes      yes  
         yes      yes
         yes      yes 
          no      yes
          no       no
```

How can I find the count of people who have taken both a housing and a personal loan?

Comment: `subset(x, housing == "yes" & personal == "yes")`. See [`?Logic`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Logic.html).

Answer (score 2):

The best way I can think of quickly doing it would be to create two vectors named "housing" and "personal":

```
housing <- c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes")
personal <- c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no")
```

Create your data frame named "k":

```
k <- data.frame(housing, personal)
k

  housing personal
1     yes      yes
2     yes      yes
3      no      yes
4     yes      yes
5     yes       no
6      no      yes
7     yes       no
8     yes       no
```

Then use the "with()" function to evaluate your data.

```
with(k, table(housing, personal))

       personal
housing no yes
    no   0   2
    yes  3   3
```

Comment: "Then use the `table()` function..."

Comment: i still need to learn this function, 
i will study about it and its usgae,

thank you btw.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find the count of people who have taken both a housing and a personal loan?

You can do

```r
df <- data.frame(
  housing = c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes"), 
  personal = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no"))
sum(df$housing == "yes" & df$personal == "yes")
#R [1] 3
```

Comment: there is a small confusion. I am new in R so kindly forgive to ask this basic question.

Sum function provide sum for a vector so in this case does it counts all housing loan customer and personal loan customer seperately and gives a sum of it?

or

Does it count customers who has availed both personal and housing loan and provided a sum for it??

Comment: `df$housing == "yes" & df$personal == "yes"` returns a logical vector which is `TRUE` if both the `df$housing == "yes"` and `df$personal == "yes"` element is `TRUE` (see `help("&")`). `sum` converts the input to a numerical vector so `TRUE` becomes one and `FALSE` becomes zero.